# Why is my new Raspberry Pi 3 shutting down after inactivity?

Tags: backup, shutdown

My new Raspberry Pi 3 seems to shut down after a certain amount of inactivity. Is that intended behaviour? I've not found any documentation that says specifically whether this is supposed to happen, or how it can be disabled.

Comment: The pi is _not_ supposed to shut down after inactivity, unless you have `xscreensaver` installed. Are you sure the pi is shutting down, or is it just you monitor?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We prefer that you ask one question per post, rather than multiple—I've edited this to just focus on the first point; feel free to ask any other distinct questions separately. That said, your last two questions probably aren't well suited to this site—you'd probably have better luck searching using Google or something similar for an existing tutorial. You might like to take a look at our tips in the [tour] and [ask] to learn how this site works a little more.

Comment: Thanks to both scitronboy and Aurora0001 for the help and clarification. I will check the xscreensaver and see if it is enabled. If I may, may I another - outside of unplugging and plugging bak in or turning off and on the power strip, is there another way to do so for the pi 3?

Comment: It would help if you stated which OS you are using.